# unix command line program does not exit after closing stdin

Tags: java, process

I create a `Process` object in Java (the program is html tidy if that is important), feed it some data via stdin (`Process.getOutputStream()`), and closed the stream, but when I call `Process.waitFor()` it never returns because the process doesn't exit. How do I fix this without calling `Process.destroy()`?

Comment: No, I just couldn't find this answer else where and thought others might benefit from what I have learned.

Comment: Why are you guys down voting this? Do I need to rephrase my question?

Comment: Do you really need a Unix version of the same answer?

Comment: I thought it would be confusing if I just said "The program doesn't exit after closing stdin", since many programs don't even read it, but most Unix utilities do.

Comment: Now that I see your duplicate question tag, I see your point. I'm going to leave this here though so others can find that answer with the search terms I was using.

Answer (score -3):

It is possible that `tidy` is waiting for you to consume the output before it exits. This is likely if you just feed the program a lot of data and it is returning a lot of data for you. The solution is to consume the output before waiting for the program to exit. This is how I am handling it (not full code):

```
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
    //-*snip*-
    Process p = null;
    Throwable error = null;
    int returnCode = -1;
    String output = null;
    StringBuilder stdErr = new StringBuilder(200);
    try{
        p = builder.start();
        try (Writer w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.
                getOutputStream()))){
            w.write(html);
        }
        Process reference = p;
        //read both outputs so tidy has no reason to wait
        Thread errReader = new Thread(()->{
            StringBuilderWriter writer = new StringBuilderWriter(stdErr);
            try {
                IOUtils.copy(reference.getErrorStream(), writer,
                        Charsets.UTF_8);
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                //nom...
                //An IOE that happens here will likely happen when reading
                //stdout as well.
            }
        });
        errReader.start();
        //tidy might be waiting for us to consume output
        output = IOUtils.toString(p.getInputStream());
        returnCode = p.waitFor();
        errReader.join();
    }
```

Comment: Since you want to keep question for others to find, as a stepping stone to duplicate question, you can recover some rep by deleting the answer to clear the negative rep it's giving you.

Comment: I could, but the answer might be useful to someone and it isn't that much rep. I'd rather help others than have a wealth of rep.